# Random errors appearing in Lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, slime, unbound

I'm learning Common Lisp with SLIME in Portacle. My problem is that different errors are appearing when I evaluate the same code. This code is trying to find the sum of all primes under 2000000.

```
(defparameter *n* 2000000)

(let ((sum 0) (primes (loop for i from 0 to (1- *n*) collecting t)))
  (do ((i 2 (1+ i)))
      ((>= i *n*))
    (if (elt primes i)
        (progn
          (setf sum (+ sum i))
          (do ((mul (+ i i) (+ mul i)))
              ((>= mul *n*))
            (setf (elt primes mul) nil)))))
  (format t "Sum:~d" sum))
```

Just before, it said variable `I` was unbound, then it said variable `MUL` was, and now it tells me `PRIMES` is. What's happening here?

To be more precise, what I did was click Compile/Load file > click Eval And Pretty-Print.

Comment: I don't know Portacle at all, but it's pretty clear you're only evaluating *parts* of the expression: you need to evaluate all of it.  However there's another problem here: you're using lists like arrays which will result in terrible performance (quadratic in this case I think).  The calculation you want to do will probably take hours, compared with fractions of a second if you use arrays.

Comment: Can't reproduce. I suspect that @tfb is right that you are not evaluating all of the code; tfb is certainly right about the poor performance characteristics.

Comment: I suspected that too, I'll research more about it. Also, thanks for pointing out the performance problem. I shouldn't have assumed that lisp lists were python lists.

Answer (score 0):

Put the cursor outside the code, and then click Eval And Pretty-Print. That would evaluate the whole code.